# Como quitarle el foco a un control Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms, botón

Estoy trabajando en una app Windows Forms en el cual tengo un formulario con un botón y un TextBox lo que deseo es que cuando preciono el botón para hacer un proceso cuando termine darle el foco a un TextBox.

El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
private void OnAplicarDescuento(SelectedAplicarDescuento obj)
    {
        if (obj.Descuento >= 0 && obj.PrecioVenta != 0)
        {
            txtDescuento.Text = $"{obj.Descuento:N2}";
            txtPrecioVenta.Text = $"{obj.PrecioVenta:N2}";

            // Trato de darle el foco al control Textbox.
            Utilidades.ChangeControlStyles(btnAplicarDescuento, ControlStyles.StandardClick, false);
            ActiveControl = txtPrecioVenta;
            txtPrecioVenta.Select();
        }
    }
```

Método

```
// Para perder el foco de un control
    public static void ChangeControlStyles(Control ctrl, ControlStyles flag, bool value)
    {
        MethodInfo method = ctrl.GetType().GetMethod("SetStyle", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (method != null)
            method.Invoke(ctrl, new object[] { flag, value });
    }
```

La imagen donde quiero quitarle el foco al botón solo se le va el foco cuando hago click en otro control.

[image: Quitar foco]

Answer (score 0):

Usa el método `focus()`. Uno pensaría que `select()` lo hace, pero no es asi.

También, mira la respuesta a esta pregunta: [Diferencias entre los métodos Select, Focus y BringToFront](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/f2c03587-29bc-4991-a7a6-a08bcfe887d1/diferencias-entre-los-mtodos-select-focus-y-bringtofront?forum=vcses)

```
private void OnAplicarDescuento(SelectedAplicarDescuento obj)
{
    if (obj.Descuento >= 0 && obj.PrecioVenta != 0)
    {
        txtDescuento.Text = $"{obj.Descuento:N2}";
        txtPrecioVenta.Text = $"{obj.PrecioVenta:N2}";

        // Trato de darle el foco al control Textbox.
        txtPrecioVenta.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: En Windows Forms de Visual Studio `focus` no sirve para darle el foco a un control en cambio para `vb6.0` si lo hace bien.

Comment: Para darle el foco a un control uso `ActiveControl = NombreControl`

Comment: Focus es para darle el foco, en Windows Forms.

Answer (score -1):

```
private bool aplicardescuento(object SelectedAplicarDescuento )
    {
        //Agregar codigo
        return true;
    }
 private void ayudaToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object obj= new object();
            if (aplicardescuento(obj))
            {
                textBox1.Select();
            }
            else
        {
            //otra tarea
        }
    }
```

Comment: genera como bool aplicardescuento, si este se ejecuta correctamente entonces el texbox1 se seleccionara, de lo contrario tu decidirás otro procedimiento

Answer (score -1):

Logré solucionarlo de la siguiente manera:
Cambiando de foco cuando regresaba del evento.

```
var argPrecioBase = new ConstructorArgument("precioBase", Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrecioBase.Text));
            var frm = CompositionRoot.Resolve<FrmAplicarDescuento>(argPrecioBase);
            _hub.Subscribe<SelectedAplicarDescuento>(OnAplicarDescuento);
            frm.ShowDialog();
            ActiveControl = txtPrecioVenta;
            txtPrecioVenta.Select();
```

Saludos!